# actionscript 3 flash - put game on android device?

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3

I made a small game in actionscript 3, tested in device central and it works fine. I would like to know how i can install it on my phone - android htc? Does anyone know how i could achieve this, or know of any tutorials? thanks.

Comment: if you're phone has Android 2.2+, you can simply publish the game as an AIR application.  http://www.adobe.com/products/air/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=123 and http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=124.

Comment: Hi, im using actionscript 3.0 and this seems to be using adobe air to create? do you know of any other tutorials similar to this?

Comment: Adobe air is just the platform that it is published to (publish settings), rather than flash player. The code and program are identical.

Answer (score 1):

If your Phone processor is 1Ghz, sure you can.

- You need to install Adobe AIR 2.7(latest version) in your HTC
- Publish your .fla file with the AIR for Android(For this you need not to buy any certificates)For this I recommend Flash professional in CS5.5
- Transfer the result .apk file to your device.(If you face trouble sending .apk into your device since android doesn't support transferring .apk files(I am facing this), change the extension of .apk like .jpg(only for testing purpose).
- When transferred, change the extension again back to .apk and install.

  Thats it, you can run your application in your device.